# Unable to change the color of canvas Text

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm new to canvas and doing some cool animation using canvas .I got a code from internet and tried to change the color of text but unable to do so.The animation is working and everything is working properly but the font color

**HTML PART**

```
<body style="margin:0px;background-color:#3c818f">
  <canvas id="canv" onmousemove="canv_mousemove(event);" onmouseout="mx=-1;my=-1;">
    you need a canvas-enabled browser, such as Google Chrome
  </canvas>
  <canvas id="wordCanv" width="500px" height="500px" style="border:1px solid black;display:none; color: #616161">
  </canvas>
  <textarea id="wordsTxt" style="position:absolute;left:-100;top:-100;" onblur="init();" onkeyup="init();" onclick="init();"></textarea>
```

**UPDATES JAVASCRIPT**

```
  var pixels=new Array();
    var canv=$('canv');
    var ctx=canv.getContext('2d');
    var wordCanv=$('wordCanv');
    var wordCtx=wordCanv.getContext('2d');
    var mx=-1;
    var my=-1;
    var words="";
    var txt=new Array();
    var cw=0;
    var ch=0;
    var resolution=1;
    var n=0;
    var timerRunning=false;
    var resHalfFloor=0;
    var resHalfCeil=0;

    function canv_mousemove(evt)
    {
      mx=evt.clientX-canv.offsetLeft;
      my=evt.clientY-canv.offsetTop;
    }

    function Pixel(homeX,homeY)
    {
      this.homeX=homeX;
      this.homeY=homeY;

      this.x=Math.random()*cw;
      this.y=Math.random()*ch;

      //tmp
      this.xVelocity=Math.random()*10-5;
      this.yVelocity=Math.random()*10-5;
    }
    Pixel.prototype.move=function()
    {
      var homeDX=this.homeX-this.x;
      var homeDY=this.homeY-this.y;
      var homeDistance=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(homeDX,2) + Math.pow(homeDY,2));
      var homeForce=homeDistance*0.01;
      var homeAngle=Math.atan2(homeDY,homeDX);

      var cursorForce=0;
      var cursorAngle=0;

      if(mx >= 0)
      {
        var cursorDX=this.x-mx;
        var cursorDY=this.y-my;
        var cursorDistanceSquared=Math.pow(cursorDX,2) + Math.pow(cursorDY,2);
        cursorForce=Math.min(10000/cursorDistanceSquared,10000);
        cursorAngle=Math.atan2(cursorDY,cursorDX);
      }
      else
      {
        cursorForce=0;
        cursorAngle=0;
      }

      this.xVelocity+=homeForce*Math.cos(homeAngle) + cursorForce*Math.cos(cursorAngle);
      this.yVelocity+=homeForce*Math.sin(homeAngle) + cursorForce*Math.sin(cursorAngle);

      this.xVelocity*=0.92;
      this.yVelocity*=0.92;

      this.x+=this.xVelocity;
      this.y+=this.yVelocity;
    }

    function $(id)
    {
      return document.getElementById(id);
    }

    function timer()
    {
      if(!timerRunning)
      {
        timerRunning=true;
        setTimeout(timer,33);
        for(var i=0;i<pixels.length;i++)
        {
          pixels[i].move();
        }

        drawPixels();
        wordsTxt.focus();

        n++;
        if(n%10==0 && (cw!=document.body.clientWidth || ch!=document.body.clientHeight)) body_resize();
        timerRunning=false;
      }
      else
      {
        setTimeout(timer,10);
      }
    }

    function drawPixels()
    {
      var imageData=ctx.createImageData(cw,ch);
      var actualData=imageData.data;

      var index;
      var goodX;
      var goodY;
      var realX;
      var realY;

      for(var i=0;i<pixels.length;i++)
      {
        goodX=Math.floor(pixels[i].x);
        goodY=Math.floor(pixels[i].y);

        for(realX=goodX-resHalfFloor; realX<=goodX+resHalfCeil && realX>=0 && realX<cw;realX++)
        {
          for(realY=goodY-resHalfFloor; realY<=goodY+resHalfCeil && realY>=0 && realY<ch;realY++)
          {
            index=(realY*imageData.width + realX)*4;
            actualData[index+3]=255;
          }
        }
      }

      imageData.data=actualData;
      ctx.putImageData(imageData,0,0);
```

These are my code I'm trying to do the text animation. Please help me

Comment: It would normally be in the line `wordCtx.fillStyle="white";` But I feel your code is actually doing some kind of particle effect over this text, so we'll actually need the part where `pixels` is being used, because my gut says that this part is only used as some kind of color blind alpha check.

Comment: Yeah It;s a text particle effect i was trying to do

Comment: So please show the actual drawing part, the one that will use the `Pixel`s stored in `pixels`.

Comment: I have updated my entire Javascript code In  main Question

Comment: So at the line `actualData[index+3]=255;` only the alpha channel is updated, this means that the R,G&B channels will stay at their default `0` value => black pixels. To set a color, add `actualData[index]=R;actualData[index+1]=G;actualData[index+2]=B;` where `R`,`G`&`B` will be 0-255 ints.

Comment: `particles.html:147 Uncaught ReferenceError: R is not defined`. I get error after adding `actualData[index]=R;actualData[index+1]=G;actualData[index+2]=B;`

Comment: "*where `R`,`G`&`B` will be 0-255 ints.*". You need to define these variables to integers comprised between 0 and 255...

Comment: var R = 0-225;
var G = 0-225;
var B = 0-255;

Is it the way?

After I add this to my server no more error fetched but the color did not change .I give in fillStyle(255,255,255)

Comment: no... "*integers comprised between 0 and 255*" I don't know how to put in other words... If you want white, then set them all to `255`. If you want red, set  `R=255,G=0,B=0`.

Comment: No, I mean how to put the range 0-255 .I put 255 then it is fixed one

Comment: Well yes, you have to chose which color you want. An additive color is made of three channels, red, green and blue, and the ImageData object you have exposes these channels as a flatten Array where there is also a fourth Alpha channel. All these channels should be set to an integer which value goes from 0 to 255 representing the instensity of this channel.

Comment: Thnak you so much..It works properly..You please post this as an answer ,so that i could accept it